# Rotating a table so that at least two name cards are correct

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Fifteen chairs are evenly placed around a circular table. On the table are the name cards of fifteen guests. After the guests sit down, it turns out that none of them is sitting in front of their own card. Prove that the table can be rotated so that at least 2 guests are seated in front of their own name card.

The extreme case is having swapped names in pairs i.e.

1 sits where 2 should sit and vice versa, 
3 sits where 4 should sit and vice versa,...

Because no rotation will get two correctly seated, unless their number is odd from pigeon. 
Missing something? Is this really the extreme case?

Comment: If in pairs, the number is even, and then a rotation by $1$ will take lots of people to the right place.

Comment: Not if there are $20$ people, for this permutation by a rotation gives $10$ matches.

Answer (score 7):

Consider rotating the table through all possible positions.  Then every person has every card in front of them once, and so the total number of correct matches is $15$.  Since it is given that in one position there are no correct matches, the $15$ correct matches must be distributed over $14$ positions of the table.  By the pigeonhole principle, there must be a position of the table which affords at least two correct matches.

Comment: why there are no correct matches for one? They are all not matched.

Comment: Didn't you say in the question that when they sit down there are no matches?  Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: I still don't understand: why are there no correct matches in one position as the "given"?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon Sorry but I don't understand your comment.  Isn't that exactly what it says in the third sentence of the question?

Comment: @David Why must the "15 correct matches must be distributed over 14
 positions of the table?"

Comment: @JiaoCtagon How many positions of the table are there?

Comment: I don't know, 14..."

Comment: Right, and you can't have 15 matches in 15 different positions, because there aren't 15 positions, only 14.

Comment: @David How are there only `14' positions when there are '15' chairs?

Comment: Please see my previous comment (June 7).